# How to keep the ground from settling when building outdoor stairs on muddy ground

Tags: stairs

I need to install stairs to handle a six foot drop in a very muddy backyard - the stairs themselves seem easy (currently leaning towards railroad ties) but how can I make sure that the stairs don't shift as the ground settles without doing the entire thing in concrete?  The ground itself is very muddy and and is part of a "valley" between my neighbor's yard and mine.

Comment: provide a foundation - some piles may work...

Comment: I agree with Solar Mike, you need a foundation aka something to support your stair independent of the mud.

Comment: A foundation for just the bottom stair or all of the stairs?